What is a volatile default value?
The Postgres documentation says:

When a column is added with ADD COLUMN and a non-volatile DEFAULT is
specified, the default is evaluated at the time of the statement and
the result stored in the table's metadata. That value will be used for
the column for all existing rows. If no DEFAULT is specified, NULL is
used. In neither case is a rewrite of the table required.
Adding a column with a volatile DEFAULT or changing the type of an
existing column will require the entire table and its indexes to be
rewritten. As an exception, when changing the type of an existing
column, if the USING clause does not change the column contents and
the old type is either binary coercible to the new type or an
unconstrained domain over the new type, a table rewrite is not needed;
but any indexes on the affected columns must still be rebuilt. Table
and/or index rebuilds may take a significant amount of time for a
large table; and will temporarily require as much as double the disk
space.

What is a volatile default value? It's not explained in the alter table documentation I've quoted from.

See DDL Alter: 5.6.1. Adding a Column and then Tip. Basically any DEFAULT that can change between each row update.

The doc says

A VOLATILE function can do anything, including modifying the database.
It can return different results on successive calls with the same
arguments. The optimizer makes no assumptions about the behavior of
such functions. A query using a volatile function will re-evaluate the
function at every row where its value is needed.

So, when applied to the default value, a non-volatile default can be seen as being a constant (ex: true for a boolean column).
On the other hand, a volatile default value can be seen as being different for every row, such as CLOCK_TIMESTAMP recording when a row is created.

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a notably bad example, as this function is STABLE, not VOLATILE. (returns the same value inside the same transaction)

Right; you should fix the answer.
